# Appendix name repeated twice; How to get rid of the first instance?

Tags: appendices

I use for appendix the following function

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\section{appendix}

\section*{\text{Appendix I}}
```

But it gives me a double name of the section. How to 'erase' the first name for the appendix? (I wanted that it would be written 'Appendix I.').

Comment: Just remove `\section{appendix}`.

Comment: Why the `\text` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting your numbering to capital roman numerals in your appendix, then you define two sections. The first one `\section{appendix}` will print `I. appendix` or `appendix I.` depending on your section definition. It will also appear in the ToC. The second one (last line) will not appear in the ToC, it will print `Appendix I` (though i don't know, what you're trying to achieve using `\text{}`), but it won't affect the counter you especially redefined, because of the `*` (unnumbered section. I think that is not a good practice for appendicies. Though I'm guessing which document class you're using, this MWE might be more of what you want

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref,url,ifthen,listings}
\begin{document}\noindent
\section{normal title}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Roman{section}}
\section{An appendix title}
\section{Another}
This gets automatically the next number.
\end{document}
```

Every section after the redefinition gets `Appendix` and a roman numeral prepended. In the document and in the ToC.